# Bootstrap 3 Navigation Menu Without Javascript

Tags: drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

Has anyone found a way to create a responsive dropdown menu using Bootstrap 3, but without using javascript?  Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 1):

the answer is yes. such is not life:
http://mikeking.io/navigataur/

Answer (score -1):

The answer is no. You need the bootstrap js to make the menu collapsible when it responds down. Such is life.